# Need CSS of Gradient for following Image

Tags: css, gradient

Can anyone help me write the gradient CSS for the following image(without the text)?

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: upload the image here you will get css http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 5):

You could use `radial-gradient`.

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #2D84A7 5%, #0D354E);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #2D84A7 5%, #0D354E);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #2D84A7 5%, #0D354E);
}
```

Comment: I would like to add [this pretty useful link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). That is all :)

Answer (score 2):

Exercise time

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgb(49, 139, 176), rgb(14, 70, 93));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgb(49, 139, 176), rgb(14, 70, 93));
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(49, 139, 176), rgb(14, 70, 93));
}
```